# Advice on R installation and security

Tags: r

I want to install R on my work computer. The IT team declined to install it. The reason provided does not make much sense to me. Is R a security risk and does it in fact work the way they say it does. I was sent the response below and they provided the link which I also show below. I would like your advice so I can engage with the IT team and make the case to have R installed.

---

The compliance and legal teams are reviewing the implementation of a no AGPL policy. AGPL contains some of the riskiest licensing terms in the industry. It requires the distribution of source code if users modify and convey the code (including SaaS). If any of that code somehow makes its way into our product or platform, we could be forced to hand over our source code and could be sued if there is any violation of the AGPL terms.

https://opensource.google.com/docs/using/agpl-policy/

Comment: R uses GNU General Public License, not AGPL (GNU Affero General Public License)

Comment: From the r-project page "R is available as Free Software under the terms of the Free Software Foundation’s GNU General Public License in source code form. It compiles and runs on a wide variety of UNIX platforms and similar systems (including FreeBSD and Linux), Windows and MacOS." https://www.r-project.org/COPYING

Comment: What a silly reason. Installing R does not make it any more or less likely that any of its source code will be used in violation of the GPL. The R source code itself is easily available using any web browser. Same goes for the source code of just about any important free software.